# What is the single player level cap in Dragon Age: Inquisition

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

What is the single player level cap in Dragon Age: Inquisition?
I am at level 27 and I am not getting any more quests.

Answer (score 10):

[According to gamefaq](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718650-dragon-age-inquisition/70951374) and [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/dragonage/comments/2n477n/does_anyone_know_the_level_cap_for_dai/), there's a cap at 27, which you reached.

Gamefaq says :

> 27. ~27 is the soft cap.
>
> Basically, enemies stop giving experience after 24, with, I think, one exception that stops at 27. At 27, nothing gives enough experience to get to 28.

and

> Actually you can't get beyond the 27 cap no matter what (even with PC hacks). My PS4 playthrough I got to lvl 24 normally (near 100% completion). On the PC version I tried to see what the cap is and set my level/experience really high (memory hack) and the game won't let you go beyond level 27.

Reddit :

> there is a level cap at level 27 I checked by using a trainer.

That's different from what [was said about a cap by Bioware](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2014/09/05/dragon-age-inquisition-level-cap-key-is-not-to-have-a-cap-says-bioware/) and on their [forums](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/521038-what-is-the-max-amount-of-skillsabilities-you-can-achieve-in-dai/). On the forum the soft cap is said to be 30 instead of 27.

Bioware :

> They key is to not have a cap. When you arbitrary just stop getting experience, it honestly kind of sucks in my opinion. The way experience is granted in Inquistion is as you tackle monsters and going after things and as they get too low level for you they stop granting you experience. This is a fairly standard RPG mechanic and by the time you’re capped out and no longer gaining experience, you’ve killed some of the toughest stuff in the world.

Their forums :

> There is no max level cap technically but there is a soft level cap at level 30. That means that after that you'll find it really hard to gain experience from anything since enemies do not scale to your level. 30 levels is around 30 skill points, so I think we'll have enough to fill at least two trees

Which means you could get beyond 27 but that would take you a really long time (years maybe?) if there's no cap.

Comment: Could still be forever, if it's a multiplicative value of 0.